# Can't change font color in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I can trying to change font color in Excel Sheets.

Code is:

```
Sub sbChangeFontColor()

Cells(4, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 3 

Range("B4").Font.ColorIndex = 3

Cells(4, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Range("B4").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

Already, I used these code in Macros of my Excel Sheet. When I run the Macros code, Excel Sheet Font not changed and also not throwing any error messages. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Should be in a regular module, not a worksheet module then it will work for the active sheet.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error in your code..........the cells are being coloured on **some** worksheet.....the Active worksheet.

Check your sheets and Select the proper sheet before running the code.